# The click action in mailinator page does not work with protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate the verification code sent to an email in mailinator, when I run the test therror is: **"TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 35001ms"**, I'm thinking that is a problem with the async functions but I'm not secure about that.

```
const emailRow = element(by.className("tr.even.pointer.ng-scope"));
this.setCode = async function() {
    let windows =  await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    await browser.switchTo().window(windows[1]);
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(emailRow), 50000);
    browser.actions().mouseMove(emailRow).click().perform();
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(emailCode), 35000);
}
```

I also tried this

```
this.setCode = async function() {
    let windows =  await browser.getAllWindowHandles();
    await browser.switchTo().window(windows[1]);
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(emailRow), 50000);
    emailRow.click();
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(emailCode), 35000);
}
```

But I have the same problem, in the screen I can't see that the test perform the click, I put an sleep after the click in the emailRow but doesn't work, in the image there is the page that i want to perform the click.[image: Mailinator email]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use their api, instead of going to their website and read the email there. In protractor, this is very easy. depending on whether or not you have a premium account with them you can use a public or a private team inbox. In the case of a public inbox, perform something similar to the following:

```
const checkMailinatorPublicEmail = async () => {

    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

    let requestUrl = 'https://mailinator.com/api/v2/domains/public/inboxes/your_inbox_name_here';
    let responseBody = await fetch(requestUrl);
    let responseJson = await responseBody.json();
    return responseJson;
}
```

Now, you have all the email in the inbox in your response body as a json object. To keep this simple, do not use a static public team inbox, instead use a random inbox name so that each time you will only have one email in the inbox and you can parse that email to your needs.

Comment: Of course, you can make improvements on this method so that it is more dynamic. I just wanted to give you the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try the second approach. In the first approach, you are waiting for an element to be visible that does not guarantee an element is clickable.
By looking at second approach, the code looks fine. My suggestion is to try changing click method like below

```
 browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', emailRow.getWebElement());
```

Hope this will help

Happy coding!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help, what are u trying to do with the "arguments[0]" ? I don't understand that part of the code

Comment: The second parameter of function executeScript() is variable arguments. In this case, we are passing WebElement as an argument and we want to select only or we can say the first WebElement that we passed as an argument, that's why `argument[0]`